# how to center a link with two pics for every device?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

my page is structured like this:

```
<body>
  <a href="...">
    <img src="..." height="160" width="261">
    <img src="..." height="160" width="160">
  </a>
</body>
```

- what's the best way to make these two pictures exactly in the middle (next to each other) for every device?
- is it possible to do without an additional div?
- please don't ask me to use tables

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many ways you can achieve this. If you want to keep the html structure same, then you can position your anchor tag followed by 50% horizontal & vertical spacing and push it back of it's own height & width.

```
a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%; /* push it to vertically & horizontally */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* push it back of it's own width & height */
}
```

[View the demo](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/VgOEvY)

Comment: seems that I was making it too complex :) thanx! btw do you know how to make these pics stick next to each other? for now when the window is narrow the second pic goes below the first one

Comment: You can add a width value. `a{ width: 426px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
     a {
        display: flex;
        width:auto;
     }
```